# Python 2.7 Tkinter, OOP, and Callbacks

Tags: oop, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm just starting to piece together a simple utility for turning on a projector and selecting some presets on it. I was using it from a command line but then thought it would be a good excuse to start learning Tkinter. I'm struggling with the OOP design, since clearly you can do this with functions and so on. As I started adding more features and buttons, it seemed kind of crazy to have a particular callback to a one off function for each button. How do engineers deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have simillar buttons with simillar functions you can use loop (`for`) to create that buttons and you can use one function with different argument. You have to use `lambda` function to call function with arguments.

(not complet) example:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    print a, b

Button("Hello", command=lambda arg1="abc",arg2=123:my_func(arg1, arg2)).pack()
Button("World", command=lambda arg1="xyz",arg2=987:my_func(arg1, arg2)).pack()
```

You can even use list to keep arguments for all buttons.

```
def my_func(a, b):
    print a, b

buttons = (
   # title, x, y, function name, function arguments)
   ("Hello", 0, 0, my_func, ("abc", 123)),
   ("World", 0, 1, my_func, ("xyz", 987)),
)

for btn in buttons:
   title, x, y, func_name, func_args = btn

   temp = Button(title, command=lambda func=func_name, args=func_args:func(*args) )

   temp.grid(row=y, column=x)
```

Comment: That was exactly the kind of thing that I was looking for!